# MariaDB longtext REGEXP_REPLACE() - Replace All Occurrences Of Given Parameter Variable Value In A Cell

Tags: regex, replace, sql-update, mariadb

I am trying to update a longtext column full of url objects with parameters and values with this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column,'tid4=[a-z]+','tid4=NEW_VALUE');
```

That results in emptying the cell, which contains the parameter, instead of replacing all occurrences, within the cell, of the parameter no matter the value, as long as alphabetical, with the same parameter with the value I set. Any ideas what I do wrong? How to replace all occurrences of string within the whole cell?

Thanks!

Update:

Example cell content:

```
a:45:{s:4:"post";s:2:"on";s:8:"postself";s:0:"";s:4:"page";s:2:"on";s:8:"pageself";s:0:"";s:7:"comment";s:0:"";s:6:"lposts";s:2:"on";s:6:"lpages";s:0:"";s:5:"lcats";s:0:"";s:5:"ltags";s:0:"";s:6:"ignore";s:13:"about,contact";s:10:"ignorepost";s:8:"contact,";s:8:"maxlinks";i:3;s:9:"maxsingle";i:1;s:8:"minusage";i:1;s:9:"customkey";s:27851:"game, games, gaming| https://url.tld/XXX.php?sub_id=&tid1=111&tid2=222&tid3=3333&tid4=firsttest
testing, testing2| https://url.tld/XXX.php?tid1=111&tid2=222&tid3=333&tid4=secondtest
test word, word2| https://url.tld/XXX.php?tid1=111&tid2=2222&tid3=333&tid4=thirdtest";s:30:"customkey_preventduplicatelink";N;s:6:"nofoln";s:0:"";s:6:"nofolo";s:0:"";s:6:"blankn";s:0:"";s:6:"blanko";s:0:"";s:10:"onlysingle";s:2:"on";s:8:"casesens";s:0:"";s:9:"allowfeed";s:0:"";s:12:"maxsingleurl";s:1:"1";s:7:"samecat";s:2:"on";s:11:"urltemplate";s:29:"<a href="{url}">{keyword}</a>";s:10:"utfsupport";s:0:"";s:17:"disable_texturize";s:0:"";s:10:"match_slug";s:0:"";s:11:"limit_posts";i:500;s:19:"customkey_form_file";s:0:"";s:17:"append_or_replace";N;s:8:"base_url";s:2:"go";s:4:"time";i:1549483409;s:14:"visual_kw_edit";N;s:16:"custom_separator";s:1:",";s:10:"min_length";i:5;s:12:"check_plural";N;s:20:"add_instead_override";s:0:"";s:18:"nofollow_whitelist";s:0:"";s:13:"maxtotallinks";i:0;s:16:"limit_post_order";s:5:"title";s:15:"limit_post_sort";s:3:"asc";s:8:"skipdays";i:0;s:10:"trimspaces";s:2:"on";}
```

I have to make all occurances of  `tid4=whatevervalue` turn into `tid4=thesamevalue`.

I also have other things to replace like `.php?tid1= to .php?subid=&tid1= then this to .php?sub_id=newvalue&tid1=`

etc.

Comment: OK. Updating...

Comment: You're searching for the word `parameter` in your regular expression, but that word does not appear in your example cell content.

Comment: No... Parameter was just and example of parameter name. I tried it with tid4=[a-z]+ to replaec with tid4=MY_VALUE, ofc.

Comment: It works fine for me when I test it. I assume you're using MySQL 8.0.4 or later?

Comment: Yes it seems to works fine, see [this MySQL8 db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hHUFmFUm2ihAtcKjqKH7Mw/0).

Comment: Using 10.1.37-MariaDB-1~bionic - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: Works fine in MariaDB 10.2 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8cb008cf00220b14e70271a7bad2152a

Comment: Did it manually already. Could not find a solution. Phew that was on lots of places... :(

Comment: @user3377238 - See if you can simplify the failure down to something simple like`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('misc, tid4=abc, etc', 'tid4=[a-z]+','tid4=NEW_VALUE');`  It would help to know whether the bug is in `REGEXP_REPLACE` or in `UPDATE`.

Comment: @user3377238 - The `SELECT` test works for me on MariaDB 10.3.11 and 10.2.15 and 10.1.33.